# Linux shell backslash-newline for long JSON string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, json, newlines

I am using `curl` with a really long `-d, --data <data>` field containing JSON.

I would like to use backslash-newline to wrap around the JSON **in the middle of the JSON string**.

Here's an example: (creating a document in a local CouchDB instance)

```bsh
curl -X PUT --user admin \
-d '{"foo":true,"bar":true,"baz":true,"qux":true,"quux":true,"quuz":true,"corge":true,"grault":true,"spam":true,"ham":true,"eggs":true}' \
http://localhost:5984/db/foobar | jq .
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put <enter> in any place in the json as long as it's not in the middle of the key or the value.

You can also try using **heredoc**:

```
    curl -XPUT -d << EOF
"write
your
data
here"
localhost:8090/api/v1
EOF
```

Comment: It took me a minute by saying `<enter>` you just meant actually hitting enter.  It works great, thank you!